# How to make Java PieMenu half circle

Tags: java, menu

I use [PieMenu](http://dub.washington.edu:2007/projects/javadoc/edu/berkeley/guir/lib/satin/widgets/PieMenu.html) in my  Java project and i don't know how to make it half circle something like this one.
Also is there any specific way to add the icons to every JMenuItem because as stated in their notes there'are some issues related to adding items to the menu.

> Known Problems Don't do something like this:
>
> PieMenu   pieMain = new PieMenu();  JMenuItem item    = new
>   JMenuItem("File");
>
> pieMain.add(item);  item.setEnabled(false);
>
> Although this should work, it doesn't, due to a quirk in this
>   implementation. However, you can do the following instead:
>
> PieMenu   pieMain = new PieMenu();  JMenuItem item    =
>   pieMain.add("File");  item.setEnabled(false);

[image]

Comment: Can you add all your code to the question so that it would be easier just to copy and paste it over so that we can take a look and run it and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a pie menu in this [link](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~jasonh/projects/piemenu/PieMenu.java) and i had to manipulate some of the code to make it half pie